# How to dynamically create folders and place files in them as we loop through the files?

Tags: c#, loops, ssis

I want to loop through files in a folder. The files are of the format 'yyyymmdd_name'.

The Files with in the last 1 year(except the last one month) should be moved to specific folders of the format yyyymm. The folders do not exist previously and have to be created dynamically when the first file of that particular month is encountered.

This is done as part of an SSIS package which have to run every month. Can I perform this with a File system task. Do I require a Script task?

If Script task is required, can someone help as to how to implement it in C#.

How do I create the folder dynamically while looping through the files in the format of yyyymm. And where do I add the condition that if folder does not exist, create and then move file. Else just move file

Comment: Have you tried anything? Nearly anyone here can do this task, but we don't work for you.

Comment: I am just starting out in SSIS. I have tried using Script task and its working. I just want to know if its possible using File System task.

Comment: What logic are you using to identify the range of files that should be processed? I see the business rule, but physically, how have you implemented this within SSIS so we don't make bad assumptions about your implementation.

Comment: Sorry that I haven't been more clear. Suppose I have 5 files in the folder 20200231_x,  20200221_y, 20191201_z,  20191231_a, 20191101_b. I need to loop through them and they would be placed in folders 202002, 201912, 201911 according to the year and date. The folders donot exist previously but have to be created as we loop through the files by checking the month and year of the files. All files of a particular month and year, say 2019/12,should be moved to a particular folder(named 201912 in this case)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to use a [File System Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/file-system-task?view=sql-server-ver15), you'd need to use two of them.

The first will use the Create directory option.

The second will use the Move file option.

Drag the precedence constraint arrow from the first to the second to show the order of operations.

Comment: But how do I create the folder dynamically while looping through the files in the format of yyyymm. And where do I add the condition that if folder does not exist, create and then move file. Else just move file.

Comment: How do you know what yyyymm is?